# Matched junction S parameters

Tags: s-parameters, matching, reflection-coefficient

This question was asked in a competitive exam in India. Two-port S matrix is assumed here.

For matched junction S parameters, which of the following is correct ?

(a) S<sub>11</sub> not equal to 0

(b) S<sub>11</sub> equal to 0

(c) S<sub>21</sub> equal to 1

(d) |S<sub>21</sub>| equal to 0

As far as I know, matching mean "zero reflection".

I am confused between options (b) and (c). S<sub>21</sub> equal to 1 means forward transmission is 100% thereby implying that reflection at port 1 is zero (S<sub>11</sub>=0)

However, option (b) gives S<sub>11</sub> = 0 directly and so looks more appropriate. The paper setter has given option (c) as correct. I am thinking about challenging it. References to any standard textbook will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know, matching mean "zero reflection".

As you noted: It also means 100% power transfer from input to output.

So either and both of b) and c) would be correct. If only one answer is allowed then there is a 50/50 chance of getting the mark for the question.